# Tell Jenkins I want to build a specific commit in a pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline project added to Jenkins. I would like to tell Jenkins to build a specific commit in this project by using a REST query.

The project is configured as Jenkinsfile pipeline project. I would like Jenkins to get the Jenkinsfile from this specific commit I've selected, and then the pipeline script would checkout the code and perform the build.

My problem is that I can't force Jenkins to take Jenkinsfile from my selected commit. I can configure it so it'll get Jenkinsfile from `master` or any other branch, but I don't know how to parametrize the place where I want Jenkins to take Jenkinsfile from.

I.e. when building commit `foo`, I want Jenkins to checkout the repository I've provided, switch to commit `foo` and use Jenkinsfile from this commit. Next build job would want to use Jenkins to build commit `bar`; in such case Jenkins would clone the repo, switch to the `bar` commit, and start the Jenkinsfile from the `bar` commit.

Is this action supported by Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duck debugging in action.

My problem was resolved by making sure the "lightweight checkout" in the Git repository settings pane was un-checked. A bug in Jenkins?